# If integral of the square of derivative is zero, is the derivative identically zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f : \mathbb (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ be the derivative of some function $F$. Suppose $f$ is square integrable on $(0,1)$ and $\int_0^1 f(x)^2 \mathrm d x = 0$. Can we conclude $f(x) =0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$?

The point is of course that $f$ needn't be continuous. From the intermediate value theorem for derivatives, we can conclude that if $f$ is nonzero somewhere, it must be nonzero on uncountably many points. These points form some Lebesgue-nullset, but going that route didn't result in much, if anything at all.

It would be interesting if a difference would appear depending on whether it was formulated using the Lebesgue integral instead of the Riemann integral. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ah now that you edited the answer is no, let me change my current answer.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure this is wrong.. I'll think about it. My previous answer is deleted for now so others can answer too.

Comment: Intuitively I would say that there can't be an increasing point $x$ between points $y<x$ and $z>x$ arbitrarily close to each other and with $F'(y)=F'(z)=0$. So I think it's true.

Comment: I understand your intuition, we can prove that if $f(y) = c$ then $f$ is taking all the values from $0$ to $c$, it doesn't mean that $f$ is not 0 a.e... well I do not know how to answer this question.. But I really want to know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem: If $G'=g$ **everywhere** on $(a,b)$ and $g\in L^1(a,b),$  then $G(y)-G(x) = \int_x^y g$ for $a<x<y<b.$ (This is in Rudin RCA)

In our problem, suppose $F'(x)=f(x)$ everywhere in $(0,1).$ Since $\int_0^1 f^2 = 0,$ $f=0$ a.e., hence $f\in L^1.$ Thus the theorem above applies to $F,f,$ and we have $F(y)-F(x) = \int_x^y f = 0$ for all $0<x<y<1.$ This implies $F$ is constant, hence $F'=0=f$ everywhere.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_x^y g$ instead of $\int_a^b g$?

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht Yes I do, thank you.

Comment: @zhw. are you sure this theorem is true even when $g$ is not continuous?

Comment: @yanko Yes. As I said, you can find the proof in Rudin.